# I want to rename files in a directory by the name of their subdirectory

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I want to append the name of the subdirectory of a file to its file name.

This is the directory tree:

```
├── foo_nifti
│   ├──anatomical
│   │   ├──file_name.nii.gz
├──ba_nifti
│   ├──anatomical
│   │   ├──file_name.nii.gz
```

This is the command I'm using:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob

files=(*nifti/anatomical/*nii.gz)

for pathname in *nifti/anatomical/*; do newname=${PWD}; mv "$pathname" "$newname"; done
```

This command does not give me what I want. It appends the path of the directory I'm in to the file name - not the name of the subdirectory of the file to the file name.

**My desired output**

```
├── foo_nifti
│   ├──anatomical
│   │   ├──foo_nifti_file_name.nii.gz
├──ba_nifti
│   ├──anatomical
│   │   ├──ba_nifti_file_name.nii.gz
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the directories do not change, then the following will do. It is one of the may ways of course:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Use mapfile to store the found files in array 'a'
mapfile -t a < <(find . -type f -name '*.nii.gz' -printf '%P\n')

# Traverse through the array
for file in "${a[@]}"; do
  base="${file%%/*}"  # Retrieve the base dir of the file
  fname="${file##*/}" # Retrieve the file name only  
  # move original $file to 'dir/anatomical/dir_file_name  
  echo mv -v "$file" "${file%/*}/${base}_${fname}"
done
```

In case you want to know more about string manipulation then see: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100

Result will look something like:

```
renamed 'foo_nifti/anatomical/file_name.nii.gz' -> 'foo_nifti/anatomical/foo_nifti_file_name.nii.gz'
renamed 'bar_nifti/anatomical/file_name.nii.gz' -> 'bar_nifti/anatomical/bar_nifti_file_name.nii.gz'
```

In case you are satisfied with the result you can remove `echo`